# power consumption of electronic component

Tags: power-electronics

I have a question when i look into any chipset manufacturer datasheet they mention the power consumed by that chipset or any electronic component is lets say some 60mA or some XmA now is this power consumed is for one hour or for how long assuming the chipset/electronic is always on/active ?

Comment: You must first learn, what is power, voltage and currend. What is consumed in hour is energy.

Comment: Datasheets of chips almost never state the power consumption. They state the **current consumption** at a certain **supply voltage** and possibly **certain conditions of operation**. For the engineer which needs to know how much power is consumed so how long for example a battery charge will last, this is enough information. If you understand the relations between current, voltage, power and energy you will also be able to do the same. This is explained in textbooks about the basics of electricity and physics.

Comment: @FakeMoustache and this is why electrical engineers are thought as having cobs up their rear. You and 4 others easily could have answered this question and your comment almost did. Instead, you push beginners away by closing beginner questions. This isn't too broad, you knew exactly what he needed. "if your question could be answered by an entire book", you don't need an entire book to answer this question. You need a paragraph at most and an equation. Just because the answer is in many books doesn't mean it's a broad question.

Comment: @horta Then I suggest that from now on **you answer all these questions** (for which the answers can be found in a book and some studying is required) and we'll keep quiet from now on. Deal ? *Just because the answer is in many books doesn't mean it's a broad question* I think that's where opinions differ, if the answer can be found in a book, why answer it here ?

Comment: @FakeMoustache because virtually every answer on here can be found in a book. Hardly anything on here can't be found in some book. I could read an entire coding book on C to find one answer, or I could simply go to stack overflow where simple questions have simple answers and can be searched easily. IMO, the point of stack exchange is to have an easily searchable repository of quality information. Most books aren't very searchable.

Comment: @FakeMoustache A question that's too broad is something like "How does electromagnetism work?" Where there are literally **entire** books that try to answer that question.

Comment: *because virtually every answer on here can be found in a book* No that is not true, common design practices you will not find in a book. Questions that can only be answered by someone with experience in the field you will not find answered in a book. This site is about the questions **which cannot be answered from a book**. Regarding 2nd comment: that is **your** opinion and that is OK. Many people on this site have a broader opinion on what questions are "too broad".

Comment: @FakeMoustache Who do you think writes EE books? Non experienced  non-EE's? Maybe not standard EE textbooks, but certainly there are practical EE texts. Maybe the help center definition of "too broad" should be updated to be more clear then. I would have been fine with this answer being closed as a dup of some other simple q/a we have, but closing as too broad seems to go against how I read the help center definition of it. Mb I'll bring this up in meta.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Perusing Meta a bit I found an answer that points to the goal of this site located here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour. "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about electronics design." From that I would infer that even simple questions should be answered so that we can truly be the library that beginners and experts alike come to for answers. So if you don't wish to answer simple questions, is there a need to close them? Just let others answer it if it's too much hassle for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power = Voltage * Current
mA or A or Amps = Current
mV or Volts = Voltage
mW or W or Watts = Power
Energy = Power*Time

Energy consumption is often measured in Watt*hours.
Batteries are often measured in amp*hour ratings.

Basically, consumption over time is already built into the definition of current as current is literally (charge flow)/(unit time). That means it's telling you how much something is happening per unit of time. So if you want to know how much is "consumed" in 1 hour, you simply multiply by 1 hour. Unless you're looking at battery sizes, you really want watt*hours which is a measure of energy rather than an amount of charge. Use the equation above to get from mA to to watts (using voltage) and from there you can multiply that by time to get the amount of energy consumed over that time period.